# How to approach rendering different components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like some clarification of how to approach this scenario.

A new user will see Card 1, telling them to supply information and when they've completed it, Card 2 should replace Card 2 with the information they supplied.

Both Card 1 and Card 2 have different styles.

Card 1 = a, b, c, d, e
Card 2 = completed a, completed b, completed c, completed d, completed e

I know I can use ternaries like {filled ? <Card 2/> : <Card 1/> but I want to use a map since there'll be a lot of repetitive code. Is there any way to map through the cards so if the user filled out a card it'll render as a, b, completed c , d, e?

map and ternary operators

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you want to render either a `<Card1/>` or a `<Card2/>` for each field depending on whether or not it has been filled. To do this you can call the `.map()` function on the array of fields and pass in a function to check whether each field has been filled and conditionally return the appropriate card. Store the value returned by the `.map()` function in a constant, then include the constant in your render method.

For example:

```
const fields = [a, b, c, d, e];
const cards = fields.map(field => {filled ? <Card2/> : <Card1/> });

render(
  <div>
    {cards};
  </div>
)
```

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components) is the relevant documentation from the React website